# Erro ao iniciar Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, instalador

Após instalar o Android Studio, ao abrir(pela primeira vez) você escolhe o tema e a seguinte tela aparece:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu do 'Retry' não faz nada, se eu do Cancel aparece a seguinte mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas é possível que o erro seja a falta do Maven instalado na máquina. Consegue verificar isso?

Comment: Oque é Maven? Me explica fazendo favor

Comment: Maven é um gerenciador de dependências e sistema de build para Java. Se possível, instale no seu computador para ver se resolve o problema: https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/windows-prerequisites.html.

Answer (score 1):

Eu vinha enfrentando este mesmo problema no Windows 7 quando eu iniciava o Android Studio pelo Atalho do Menu Iniciar....

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Solução: Execute como Administrador

O problema estava ocorrendo por causa de permissões de disco no Drive C:. Executando o programa como administrador permitiu que o mesmo executasse o download de todos os componentes necessários e agora eu posso abrir o Android Studio normalmente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]